# Map File Descriptor to Standard Output in node js

Tags: node.js, file, stdout

How can we map file descriptor in Node js to the standard output of the process.
I tried this

```
fs=require('fs')
fd=fs.openSync('./abc.txt','w+');
process.stdout.fd=fd;
```

This changes the descriptor in process from 0 to the file descriptor but still when i do console.log the messages are not going to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get nodejs script output into the file use OS redirection:

```
node script.js >> abc.txt
```

Comment: is there any other way, in which i can redirect it in the application itself?